# Flow error - Property not found in xxx

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, immutable.js, flowtype

When I specify that `{ store }` is of type [immutable.js Map](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map), I get this error:

> [flow] [flow] property `store` (Property not found in Map) var store:
>   any

code:

```
export const Width = (props: any, { store }: Map<*,*>) => {
```

How do I get rid of the error?

Comment: is `store` a property of `Map`? I don't see it in the docs

Comment: @GabrielePetronella It isn't a property of Map. It is a Redux store being passed in which is of type `Map`.